# How to configure a stronger password encryption with JBoss 4?

Tags: security, encryption, jboss, passwords

As I understand, for JBoss 4.0.5 password encryption is mainly configured in server/.../conf/login-config.xml:

```
   <authentication>
      <login-module code = "org.jboss.security.ClientLoginModule" flag = "required">
         <module-option name = "password-stacking">useFirstPass</module-option>
         <module-option name = "multi-threaded">true</module-option>
         <module-option name = "ignorePasswordCase">false</module-option>
         <module-option name = "hashAlgorithm">md5</module-option>
         <module-option name = "hashEncoding">hex</module-option>
         <module-option name = "hashCharset">UTF-8</module-option>
      </login-module>
   </authentication>
```

Is it possible to configure something stronger than md5? And if so, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, looks like I found the ultimate answer. Extend e.g. `org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule` and override

```
protected String createPasswordHash(String,String,String)
```

to use whatever algorithm you like to create and return the hash. 
The second parameter of the method is the password to be hashed.

Then set your class into the configuration (e.g. login-config.xml). Note that the configuration (e.g. login-config.xml) still needs an algorithm to be specified. I have just put

```
<module-option name = "hashAlgorithm">FOO</module-option>
```

there.

Important note: To decide if a password is valid it is hashed and compared with the previously hashed password. This does not work for algorithms like bcrypt, which comes with its own check method, because typically each hashing on the same input creates a different salt and thus a different hash. For these algorithms you would have to override the `login()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the `hashAlgorithm` to `SHA` if you want better security than `MD5`. See [this post](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/jboss4guide/r5/html/ch8.chapter.html) for more information (specifically section 8.5.3.2. Password Hashing.

**UPDATE**

From the linked site, it says

> The name of the java.security.MessageDigest algorithm to use to hash the password. There is no default so this option must be specified to enable hashing. Typical values are MD5 and SHA.

After looking at the [java.security.MessageDigest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/MessageDigest.html) class, it appears you can provide:

- MD5
- SHA-1
- SHA-256

Comment: @mb-td I've updated my answer with further research that I found on my originally provided link.

Comment: NO! They're all **absolutely terrible** password hashes.

Comment: Hm. How can I specify something stronger? I guess I would have to change the java.security.Provider to be used. Is that somehow possible with JBoss 4.0.5?

Comment: I guess it has to do with the words “NO!” and “absolutely terrible”.

Comment: MD5 is terrible because super fast. **Speed is exactly what you don't want here**. Best way is BCRYPT, but it's not a Jboss standard yet.